# why Google Cloud Messaging notification not working with iPhone production environment?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an iPhone application which receive Push notifications from PHP server.

For sending notifications I'm using Google Cloud Messaging. GCM works fine in iPhone Development environment but I am not able to receive notification with iPhone production environment & I keep getting this **error message** :

```
{
    "multicast_id":7214972633373567187,
    "success":0,
    "failure":1,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[
        {
            "error":"NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried lot and also googled lot but didn't find any solution to solve this issue. Please help me out.

I created `.p12` production environment certificates and uploaded it to Google Cloud Messaging configuration file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. now using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) I am able to send notification to iPhone devices.

In `appDelegate.m` just need to change one condition in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method.

Here's the code to use for **production** environment :

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
```

Here's the code to use for **development** environment :

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
```

Comment: I did it this way:

#ifdef DEBUG
    // needed for the debug/test build
    NSNumber *sandbox = @YES;
#else
    NSNumber *sandbox = @NO;
#endif
    NSDictionary *registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:sandbox};

Answer (score 2):

Set `"priority": "high"`

```
{
      "to": "gcm_device_token",
      "priority": "high",
      "content_available": false,
      "notification": {
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": "1",
        "title": "Push Title",
        "body": "Push Body"
      }
    }
```

Here's the code to use for production environment :
appDelegate.m

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
```

Here's the code to use for development environment :
appDelegate.m

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `iPhone push notifications in Production` environment you need to follow a couple of things:

1. Your `.cer` and `.p12` need to be created using `production profile`
2. Your app needs to be uploaded on `iTunes store`.
3. **Only** when you download the `binary` from `iTunes store` , your production profile will come in play and you can send and receive messages in Production environment.

Comment: thanks for your ans. I created all certificates in production environment and also uploaded all certificates on Google Cloud Messaging services but not received single notification with production environment

Comment: @nishitpatel when we are talking about iPhone why to upload on GCM? I guess, in ideal conditions you create .cer and .p12 , then create .pem(s) out of them. Once you have both .pem(s) ,you combine then in 1, and then use it in your code

Comment: you are right but iPhone push notification not supported on my server so i used GCM to avoid server conflict.

Comment: then you are doing it the wrong way. And I am not sure what do you mean by iPhone push notifications not supported on your server. All it needs is php and curl support to send iPhone push notifications if you are using APNs.